# Parsing two xml files together

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser

I have two `xml` files which i need to parse at the same time using NSXMl parser (not sequentially). These files have different data that will be displayed in `uiLabel's` in `tableviewCell`. I have successfully parse one xml file. I have also looked into apple docs but it says you can only parse one xml file at a time. is there any other way of doing it? Please help

That is how i am currently parsing two xm files.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{

```
if(!_suraDict || ![_suraDict count])
{
    _suraTitle = [NSMutableArray array];
    _suraDict =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    _indexArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"simple" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSData *Mydata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    _transTitle = [NSMutableArray array];
    _transDict =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    _indexArray2 = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *filePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en.yusufali" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSData *Mydata2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath2];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:Mydata];
    NSXMLParser *parser2 = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:Mydata2];

    [parser2 setDelegate:self];
    [parser2 parse];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}

else{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
       self.detailViewController.detailItem = [ _suraDict valueForKey:[_indexArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem2 = [ _transDict valueForKey:[_indexArray2 objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }

[super viewDidLoad];

   self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}


    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"sura"]){

        _sura = [NSMutableString string];

        _sura = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"aya"]){
        _aya = [NSMutableString string];

        [_suraTitle addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"text"]];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"sura"]){
        [_suraDict setObject:_suraTitle forKey:_sura];
        [_indexArray addObject:_sura];
        _suraTitle = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

     //  NSLog(@"foundCharacters : %@", string);

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

    [[AppDelegate modelController]setcountArrayDict:_suraDict];
    [[AppDelegate modelController]setIndexArray:_indexArray];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = [ _suraDict valueForKey:[_indexArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}

- (void)parser2:(NSXMLParser *)parser2 didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict2{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"sura"]){

        _sura2 = [NSMutableString string];

        _sura2 = [attributeDict2 objectForKey:@"name"];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"aya"]){
        _trans = [NSMutableString string];

        [_transTitle addObject:[attributeDict2 objectForKey:@"text"]];
    }

}

- (void)parser2:(NSXMLParser *)parser2 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"sura"]){
        [_transDict setObject:_transTitle forKey:_sura2];
        [_indexArray2 addObject:_sura2];
        _transTitle = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}

- (void)parser2:(NSXMLParser *)parser2 foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

        NSLog(@"foundCharacters : %@", string);

}

- (void)parser2DidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser2{

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.detailViewController.detailItem2 = [ _transDict valueForKey:[_indexArray2 objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender   //valueforkey means the aayahs
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        DetailViewController *viewcontroller= [segue destinationViewController];
        viewcontroller.selectedRow=indexPath.row;
        [viewcontroller setDetailItem:[ _suraDict valueForKey:[_indexArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]];
        [viewcontroller setDetailItem2:[ _transDict valueForKey:[_indexArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you parsing two xml files into one UITabeView?

Comment: Yes, i have two labels inside uitableviewcell which i need to populate with it. i have parse one files into one label but second one is not parsing. it seems to me a reason of setting delegate because i can only set delegate to one file at a time

Comment: What's the problem with parsing them one after the other? If it's for a TableView, you can reloadData after you finish parsing both.

Comment: I must have done something wrong. i am posting my code here. Please have a look what i have done wrong please

Comment: Naming the delegate methods differently won't work (NSXMLParser will always call the exact name per the protocol).  In each delegate method, either check which file is being parsed currently, or (better), create separate parser classes for each file.

Comment: @Anna How would i know which file is currently being parsed?

Comment: The delegate methods have a `parser` parameter which you can check directly if you declare your NSXMLParsers as ivars.  Then you can do `if (parser == data1Parser) { ... } else { ... }`.  But the much better way to go is to parse each file in its own delegate class.

Comment: It works perfect now. Have no words to thank you :) i spent days figuring it out.